# How to correctly infer T for an RxJS Subject<T> from generic function with type constraint

Tags: typescript, rxjs, typescript-generics

I have a module that provides the ability for callers to subscribe to a discrete set of events. When a caller subscribes for a given event, they provide the event name as the first argument. From that argument, I would like to be able to infer the callback signature.

The implementation uses an RxJS `Subject` for each supported event, and creates a subscription to it for every call to `myModule.subscribe(eventType)`. A stripped back version of the implementation is shown below (you can also see this running on [this TS Playground workspace](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgZQK4CMBWBTAxjAGhQwGdcpgwZgIA7OAXzgDMoIQ4AiKAD0xM4BuAFDDcdEvACiAN2y0YAOQCGIbCTgBeRMLh64ygFxdlnArv3pjndGYt7c13HabKN42pJHCYATzDYcAAKyr4ANhDKACYa2gj2cADasvJKquoAdMoAusaSFLQA5iL6SSkKKmokGei5cLSoIOjYUCX6yXIV6dW4degQEGHYyrQiDN5+AXDlMAAq-upacADW2L4QzHCT2BvTnWlV3gD0R3CotDT0u8phYXCQJCTA6ENw2PskPgt7qSQAPLMAHxLWZvHgweQxH4KeYBDQAfkQ22MsyIYFCEWixhC4UiMUSs2yTGMtHeLWOp3Olzg11u9wgj2er1wNzC6GUuGWn22cAAwqz2ZyAcDtKDsODIRoZrDFoiABRkhTGGb-IEASi0wJkEGAUTgJLJrVEJzOFzoNM2rPpjJegUV8BIGBw+G53zQWDwMFVIrgYoltCh0oWCOIHvwfxVwuBBrkRrEEng4lunup2lJAHc4ABZZRgCP7GUkIju51e-OpQuAwFytXeDySFi0ADqwBgAAteQmoMpgAolgCwRCA1KC8HqwlaOkUeZSrgrHyBRzlsLhGrjO6yBQqNSAD71VB0zTA+KzhNwR1h+DaJNDfCXDJttxyydqNUJUqIm8pugZQrYGDPukb6lKUBqZiWnrlgo3rVrWcAmhmoalnAwCbOmgRRHQADk8A3FAwxRL4cCPnINKkgkCSoXAcoXshACEmjaOcUTYMwvbYFEGoniBDiDLe1A-iQ-6AWoRC0Z6tbvvo9YOqQ5CUAJ9DaOJ+AZBem7PNgcpzsBPFwPhMCoFA9DqfJ250G0egMKIpQGUZ9ANLcYyiMwzath2XY9goco2GY1H2hqR5wPWgzYBkESFAq+xqpJJrigE+BbAsuz2nAAC0x5JQE1i2II9wYniJKNM0rSMMIQA))

```js
import { Subject, Subscription } from "rxjs";

const EventNames = {
    a: "a",
    b: "b",
    c: "c",
} as const;

type Payloads = {
    [EventNames.a]: string;
    [EventNames.b]: number;
    [EventNames.c]: boolean;
};

type EventTypes = keyof typeof EventNames;

// all possible event objects
type Events<T> = T extends EventTypes ? {type: T, payload: Payloads[T]} : never;

// all possible callbacks
type Callback<T> = T extends EventTypes ? (event: Events<T>) => void : never;

// all possible subjects
type Subjects<T> = T extends EventTypes ? Subject<Events<T>> : never;

const collection = new Map<EventTypes, Subjects<EventTypes>>();

function fnWithConstraint<T extends EventTypes>(
    name: T,
    cb: Callback<T>
): Subscription | null {
    const subject = collection.has(name)
        ? collection.get(name)
        : new Subject<Events<T>>();
    
    if (subject !== undefined) {
        collection.set(name, subject); 
        /* ^ Type '{ type: "a"; payload: string; }' is not assignable 
           to type 'Events<T>'.
         */
        const subscription = subject.subscribe(cb)
        /* ^ This expression is not callable. Each member of the union 
           type '{ (observer?: Partial<Observer<Events<T>>> | undefined): 
           Subscription; (next: (value: Events<T>) => void): Subscription; 
           ... 1 more ...' has signatures, but none of those signatures 
           are compatible with each other.
         */
        return subscription;
    }

    return null;
}

fnWithConstraint("b", (event) => console.log(event));
// expect typeof event -> { type: "b"; payload: number; }
```

I can't get this to compile successfully. The TS Playground I've linked to shows the correct result that I'm after on line:45, but the compiler is complaining about the Subjects type signature, and I can't seem to resolve it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to overload your function:

```js
import { Subject, Subscription } from "rxjs";

const EventNames = {
  a: "a",
  b: "b",
  c: "c",
} as const;

type Payloads = {
  [EventNames.a]: string;
  [EventNames.b]: number;
  [EventNames.c]: boolean;
};

type EventTypes = keyof typeof EventNames;

// all possible event objects
type Events<T extends EventTypes> = { type: T, payload: Payloads[T] }

// all possible callbacks
type Callback<T extends EventTypes> = (event: Events<T>) => void

// all possible subjects
type Subjects<T extends EventTypes> = Subject<Events<T>>

const collection = new Map<EventTypes, Subjects<EventTypes>>();

function fnWithConstraint<T extends EventTypes>(
  name: T,
  cb: Callback<T>
): Subscription | null
function fnWithConstraint(
  name: EventTypes,
  cb: Callback<EventTypes>
): Subscription | null {
  const subject = collection.has(name)
    ? collection.get(name)
    : new Subject<Events<EventTypes>>()

  if (subject !== undefined) {
    collection.set(name, subject);
    return subject.subscribe(cb)
  }
  return null

}

fnWithConstraint("b", (event) => console.log(event));
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?allowSyntheticDefaultImports=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgZQK4CMBWBTAxjAGhQwGdcpgwZgIA7OAXzgDMoIQ4AiKAD0xM4BuAFDDcdEvACiAN2y0YAOQCGIbCTgBeRMLhxlALi7LOBXXHRHO6U%20dxXctpso3jakkcJgBPMNjgACsreADYQygAmGtoI5gDasvJKquoAdMoAukaSFLQA5iJ6CXIKKmokqehZcLSoIOjYUIVwxUllabjV6BAQIdjKtCIMnj5%20cIkKACq%206lpwANbY3hDMcKPYK%20MlyeWeAPR7%20iEhcJAkJMDofXDY23AQWHgwJF4zW0kkADyTNzww8lF3lMZiQAHxzJDrIyTIhgYJhSJGIKhcJROKTDKMUQHI4nM4XK7%20XDKY7oZS4eYvdZwADCJJCZIp31%20-1ogImMGmfjBcwAFLckkYOV9JqCAJRacEyCDACLYw7004Qc6Xa4kDA4fBUt5oR5a5nYP4AjQcrnqcHaXWamCfYXfUGg0RuSRwcTHJ40ejaWjYADucAAssowLbtmaSEQrU8vqaQQ7eWLPMxULR8J6WLQAOrAGAACxpEhgUGUwAUBqNbJNYbjvPMtBS0LMelwllp9MZ83twjFRl1ZAoVHTAB8aqhjsJk6nqHQM9m8wX3EWSwpa3p62ohdXuU3Xa26aTyZ3Y9zHT3iOh%205Rp-QR7Vjjpm4W4Oq9fBtG6%20mm6Klcy5eevsDFcw9AAfldXpP2vVI8mwGB-xSIC9D0IwfX9KN8FDD5MOBE9QQTUQ9GAVZeRfa04AAQk0bQUwibBmFLbAIglWIkPA90v1oVISFg%20C1CIUinkTYC4CgWDUCgegBPwLjSHIS5sF5FtEKxPRRJgcT6DvEJRAYURmCzHN80LYtSzg6xTDgfltglTRwWdXpsFSMI8ispIxSEnFDT8fA1hmTYBQUOAAFpwUhGYrBsQRTnhVEULqBomixIA)

In this case you should loose the strictness a bit. From the outside, this function now is safe.

Your example don't work because you use `T` which is a subtype. IT does not mean that `T` is equal to `a | b | c` it just means that `T` might be any subtype of this union.

Consider this example:

```js
function fnWithConstraint<T extends EventTypes,>(
  name: T,
  cb: Callback<T>
): Subscription | null {
  const subject = collection.has(name)
    ? collection.get(name)
    : new Subject<Events<T>>()

  if (subject !== undefined) {
    collection.set(name, subject);
    return subject.subscribe(cb)
  }
  return null
}

declare const a:'a' & {__tag:'Hello'}

fnWithConstraint(a, (event) => console.log(event));
```

`event` argument is `Events<"a" & { __tag: 'Hello'; }>`.

While TS allows you to use `const a`, it is unsafe to use `event` argument, `fnWithConstraint(a, (event) => console.log(event.type.__tag /** Hello */));`

Please keep in mind, that `a` for typescript is a regular object which can has his own subtypes. See this: `keyof 'a'`. More than 30 properties.

TS will also allow you to use this branded type with mine solution, but `event` argument will be valid/safe

---

> can class methods be overloaded in the same way

Yes.

Simple example:

```js
class Foo {
  run(arg: string): number
  run(arg: number): string
  run() {
    return 'NOT IMPLEMENTED' as any

  }
}

const result = new Foo();
result.run(42) // string
result.run('str') // number
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oCcCuA7AFGJgOYBc0EALpgJa7ECU5u2AtgEYCmm6WehJZmy6YmFanWK8cBBil4ZMnStky5oAcgByAeQAq0AJIBZAAoAZAKLHLWvZYAiG6JBe4Anql4BfVL9TA8LhUWJwQ2CCU0AC80LicAO5wiPgMANyoSuGRAHQy%20AAsAExyAPSl4rT0mWERlHn8GlSYGmUVLBzcQA)

[Official overloads documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)

Comment: TIL about function overloading. Fantastic...that did it, thanks. 

One tiny follow-up, can class methods be overloaded in the same way? The module I'm dealing with is actually an ES6 class, but I stripped my example code back to focus on the problem at hand. Given this solution, it's possible that a class isn't a suitable construct.

Comment: @JazLalli made an update